# How do I combine both Max and Count function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have written a query that asks me to print names of the farmers and the number of different types of produce they have.

They have now asked me to extend that query to only include the maximum produce and also print the farmer's name. But the catch is, I cannot use the limit function. My query is :

```
select Farmer.FarmerName, count(Produce.ProduceID) as 'Produce number'
from Supplies 
right join Farmer on Supplies.FarmerID=Farmer.FarmerID
left join Produce on Supplies.ProduceID=Produce.ProduceID
group by Farmer.FarmerName
order by count(Produce.ProduceID) desc;
```

I want the answer to both scenarios, where I only have to print the name of the Farmer with the highest Produce count. And where I have to print both, the highest produce count and the Farmer's name.

Edit: Max produce is defined as the highest sum of the different types of produce each farmer makes. Lets say a farmer produces 3 kinds of vegetables and another farmer produces 4 kinds of vegetables. The max count of vegetables would be 4.

Comment: How do you define the *maximum produce*?

Comment: *I can't use `limit`*? Please explain.

Comment: The teacher has asked me to solve this without using the function "limit". Probably to increase the difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the question, it SOUNDS like you want a list of all farmers who grow the most produce.  ie: Number of things. You could have 1 farmer grow corn, wheat, soy, and another farmer grow broccoli, squash and soy. They both grow the same number of things.  So I am guessing you want to know "what is the most number of items any single farmer is growing".  That will start your list.  You dont need to join to the farmer nor product table, since the supply has the farmer ID.  I put the order by just so you can visually see the results of which farmer (by the ID) have how many things

```
select
      S.FarmerID,
      count(*) as ThingsGrownByFarmer
   from
      Supplies S
   group by
      S.FarmerID
   order by
      count(*) DESC
```

Now, since you state you can't use a LIMIT, you can then wrap the above using a MAX() of the count per farmer such as

```
select
      max( PreQuery.ThingsGrownByFarmer ) MostThings
   from
   ( select
           S.FarmerID,
           count(*) as ThingsGrownByFarmer
        from
           Supplies S
        group by
           S.FarmerID ) PreQuery
```

So the above will now give you a SINGLE record with whatever the largest count of things grown/supplied is for ANY individual farmer.  Now, per the opening statement, it is possible that multiple farmers can grow / supply multiple items having the same maximum count of things.  Now you want all farmers who hit that count and can show them.

Now, since you state you can't use a LIMIT, you can then wrap the above using a MAX() of the count per farmer such.  In this case, I am starting my query with the MostThings for any farmer.  Then join back to the query of all counts per each farmer as long as they match the count of things produced by the highest count.  Finally join that result since we now have the farmer's ID to the farmer table to get the farmer's name.

```
select
      MaxProduced.MostThings,
      F.FarmerName
   from
   ( select
          max( PreQuery.ThingsGrownByFarmer ) MostThings
       from
          ( select
                  S.FarmerID,
                  count(*) as ThingsGrownByFarmer
               from
                  Supplies S
               group by
                  S.FarmerID ) PreQuery ) MaxProduced
             JOIN ( select
                         S.FarmerID,
                         count(*) as ThingsGrownByFarmer
                      from
                         Supplies S
                      group by
                         S.FarmerID ) AllFarmersCounts
               on MaxProduced.MostThings = AllFarmersCounts.ThingsGrownByFarmer
               JOIN Farmer F
                  on AllFarmersCounts.FarmerID = F.FarmerID
```

Many times, you need to break a question down to see what piece you are looking for.  Write a query to get that exact thing.  Then that is used to get the next layer, then you can join all the rest once the pre-requisites are done.

**Follow-up.**

To handle farmers who did not supply anything, just start with farmers and left-join to supplies where there is nothing.

```
select
      F.FarmerName
   from 
      Farmers F
         Left Join Supplies S
            on F.FarmerID = S.FarmerID
   where
      S.FarmerID IS NULL
```

To add this to the original answer, I would change to

```
[original full query]
UNION ALL
    select
          F.FarmerName,
          0 ThingsGrownByFarmer
       from 
          Farmers F
             Left Join Supplies S
                on F.FarmerID = S.FarmerID
       where
          S.FarmerID IS NULL
order by
   ThingsGrownByFarmer DESC
```

Comment: @DaniyalAhmedKhan, no problem.  You accepted another answer, but just note, that wont always be the case.  Their answer will only return 1 farmer.  What if you have 5 farmers who supply 3 things.  That answer will only return 1 farmer, not all 5.  It may be a short answer, but ensure you are getting what you are asking for.

Comment: Just checked it up. You are right, that query just returns the first one. The original query that I had was "How many types of produce are each of the farmers producing? Your result should include the names of farmers and the total number of produces. Also, include farmers who do not 
supply any produce as well. Sort the results by the highest  number of produce.

Comment: The data given did actually have two farmers having equal number of things they produced, which was also the highest in the data set

Answer (score 0):

When you group by a column, you cannot select any other column that is not included in the "group by" statement.

To show both farmer's name and the produce, you need to include them in the GROUP BY statement:

```
select Farmer.FarmerName, Produce.ProduceID, count(Produce.ProduceID) as 'Produce number'
from Supplies 
right join Farmer on Supplies.FarmerID=Farmer.FarmerID
left join Produce on Supplies.ProduceID=Produce.ProduceID

GROUP BY Farmer.FarmerName, Produce.ProduceID

ORDER BY COUNT(Produce.ProduceID) DESC
```

This query should aggregate the farmer's name and the produce id, and display it in the order of maximum produce. If you're looking for just the top farmer - produce pair, then you can include TOP 1 as such:

```
select TOP 1 Farmer.FarmerName, Produce.ProduceID, count(Produce.ProduceID) as 'Produce number'
```